# Flask get form data to celery task queue

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, celery

I'm trying to build a flask app that takes a string and a csv file from a form and perform some asynchronous tasks (basically combining the send email and longtask from this blog https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask). To achieve this, I'm using celery to run the background task. However, I am not able to pass the data from the flask form to celery task and is getting NoneType error. How can I pass the form data to celery task and start the "start_long_task" function after the form is submitted

Comment: in blog task get data as arguments, not directly from `request.form`. Task may have no access to request data. `def long_task(self, string, csv):`

Comment: I updated my post based on your suggestion, now I'm getting `the view function did not return a valid response` on terminal and `ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'`. It seems like celery is not picking up the string and csv file. Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: in `longtask` you should `print()` values in  `request.form` to see what you get. Maybe you don't get files.

Comment: yep, it's not picking up

Comment: as I remeber it should have files in separated object - `request.files`